Null check operator used on a null value With Rive
when I am Using Rive with Flutter I was use this method
RiveAnimation.asset("myAssetHere")

and evry thing fine but, when I want to set some controlle on Rive I use this code
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';

class CategoryController extends GetxController {

  Artboard? _riveArtBord;
  SMIInput<bool>? _searchHover;

  Future<void> loadAnimation() async {

    rootBundle.load('assets/animations/pro_five_star_review.riv').then((data) {
      final file = RiveFile.import(data);
      final artboard = file.mainArtboard;
      final controller =
      StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, 'Pro Five Star Review');
      if (controller != null) {
        artboard.addController(controller);
        setHoverOrNot(controller.findInput('searchHover'));
        setRiveArtBord(artboard);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    loadAnimation();
  }

  void setHoverOrNot(SMIInput<bool>? value) {
    _searchHover = value;
  }

  void setHoverOrNotValue(bool value) {
    _searchHover?.value = value;
  }

  void setRiveArtBord(Artboard? artboard) {
    _riveArtBord = artboard;
    update();
  }

  Artboard? getRiveArtBord() {
    return _riveArtBord;
  }
}

and in screen class I type this
GetBuilder<CategoryController>(
            builder: (controller) => SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: 250,
                child: Rive(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  artboard: _controller.getRiveArtBord()!,
                ),
            ),
          )

now the animation is show and evry thing good But there is still something wrong going on and that is this
Null check operator used on a null value

and Specifically, the error occurs here in this line of code
rootBundle.load('assets/animations/pro_five_star_review.riv').then((data) {
      final file = RiveFile.import(data);

but I do not know why. Is this due to the asset not loading quickly even though I put then?
I don't know what the reason is, honestly, any help from you, thank you
I want to know what caused this error
